# Recurrent solution to $v'_{n+1}+\alpha v_{n+1} = -\beta/(n+1) v'_n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Looking for a series solution to a second order PDE (namely, of the form $f(x,t) = \sum_n v_n(x) t^n$), I came across the following 'difference-differential' equation (of a kind I didn't encounter before):
\begin{align}
v'_{n+1} + \alpha v_{n+1} = - \frac{\beta}{n+1}v'_{n}.
\end{align}

I'm wondering if there is a general recurrent relation that will relate the $n=0$ terms (function and its derivatives) to the $N^{\rm th}$ terms (function and/or its derivatives). Somehow I'm unable to express this relation in the form of a matrix equation, no matter what vector form I choose. The last one I tried was $\vec{v}_n = [v'_{n+1}, v_{n+1}, v'_n, v_n]$ with a matrix equation $\mathbf{B}\vec{v}_{n+1} = \mathbf{A}_n \vec{v}_n$, specifically,
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha  & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0  & 1 & \alpha \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v'_{n+1} \\ 
v_{n+1} \\
v'_{n} \\
v_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
- \frac{\beta}{n+1}  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{\beta}{n} & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v'_{n} \\ 
v_{n} \\
v'_{n-1} \\
v_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The problem is that $\mathbf{B}$ is not invertible, so I cannot really do recursion on this. Any suggestion on how to approach the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Applying the Laplace transform we have

$$
(s+\alpha) V_n(s) = -\frac{\beta}{n+1}\left(sV_{n-1}(s)-v_{n-1}(0)\right)+v_n(0)
$$

then giving an $v_0(t)$ we can build all the sequence. For instance, with null initial conditions

$$
V_n(s) = \frac{(-\beta)^{n-1}}{(3)_{n-1}}\left(\frac{  s}{\alpha +s}\right)^{n-1}V_0(s)
$$

where $(3)_{n-1}$ is the Pochhammer function.

Comment: Super useful, thank you!